# Are there any restrictions to getting a used copy of Dragon Age Origins?

Tags: xbox-360, dragon-age-origins

I was planning to try out Dragon Age Origins on the XBox 360 and I am wondering if I should buy it new or used. What will I miss out on if I buy the used version of Dragon Age?

Mass Effect 2 has the Cerberus Network which wont work if you have a used copy of the game, you have to buy it at the marketplace.

Does Dragon Age Origins have the same kind of restrictions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My copy came along with a card with a code for the The Stone Prisoner/Shale DLC pack which retails for $15. The same card also had a code for Blood Dragon Armor in Mass Effect 2.

The DLC itself is pretty short, but the character you can add to your party isn't bad. In my opinion, it's not worth $15 to buy yourself, but you're not missing out on a whole lot.

Comment: I just checked on their site, and there is a Ultimate version of the game out now with all the DLCs and the expansion pack. So will probably get that! Thanks!